# Examples of sequences with special behaviour

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have been searching for an example of the following kind of real sequences since yesterday:

- A sequence $(a_n)$ such that it contains $(\frac{-1}{n})$ and $(\frac{1}{n})$ and converges.
- A null sequence $(a_n)$ such that the sequence $(\frac{1}{a_n})$ is not bounded and it does not tend to $-\infty$.

I have tried many examples, but none of them work. Can anybody give some ideas ?

Thanks !!

Cheers

Comment: For the first one, since both sequences you want to include converge, and converge to the same value, just intertwine them: $1,$ $-1,$ $\frac{1}{2},$ $-\frac{1}{2},$ $\frac{1}{3},$ $-\frac{1}{3},$ $\frac{1}{4},$ $-\frac{1}{4},$ $\frac{1}{5},$ $-\frac{1}{5},$ $\frac{1}{6},$ $-\frac{1}{6}, \; \ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case 
$$a_n=(-1)^n \frac{1}{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}$$ should work, when $\lfloor, \rfloor $ is the integer function.

This one has
$$a_{2n}=\frac{1}{n} \, \mbox{ and } \, a_{2n+1}=-\frac{1}{n}$$

For the second example, the same sequence should work.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Why positive? The sequence is null, and it is NOT going to $- \infty$...

Comment: Of course! My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one consider the series summed by the alternating harmonic series,
$$a_n=(-1)^n\frac {1}{n}$$
For the second one consider sequences of the form
$$a _n=\frac {1}{n^p}$$
for $p>1$.
More generally researching $p $-series (and alternating $p $-series) and looking at the sequences being summed should do the trick.

Comment: How  does the first represent a "sequence that contains $\left(\frac1n\right)$  and $\left(-\frac1n\right)$ and converges" ? Neither of those are subsequences of $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\frac1k\right)$.

Comment: Look at the sequence being summed. Those sequences still meet the requirements.

Comment: Those are **series**.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm saying look at the corresponding sequences.

Comment: @WillFisher And for what $n$ is $S_n = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @WillFisher I did and I said: $\left\{\frac1n\right\}_{n\ge 1}$ cannot be extracted as a subsequence of $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\frac1k\right\}_{n\ge1}$ namely because the first one converges to $0$ and the second one converges to $-\ln2$.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. The answers I gave are of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n $, I'm saying that for each of those $a _n $ should be the sequence taken as the answer.

Comment: Now that what you meant is clear (there is at least another sequence naturally associated to a series, and it's the sequence of partial sums), I'd point out that $$\left( (-1)^n\frac 1n\right)_{n\ge 1}=-1,\frac12,-\frac13, \frac14, -\frac15, \cdots $$ which, as you can see, does not contain $\left(\frac 1n\right)_{n\ge 1} $ as a subsequence. For instance, it never takes the value $\frac13$.